# Compare pattern of values in two arrays more efficiently

Tags: ruby, arrays, performance

I need to test two arrays for equality each containing 8 items which are integers `1..7`. The catch is that it's not the values per se I care about but the pattern of values. So for instance:

```
eq? [ 1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,1 ], [ 1,2,3,4, 7,6,5,1 ] # => true
eq? [ 1,1,2,2, 3,3,4,4 ], [ 3,3,2,2, 1,1,4,4 ] # => true
eq? [ 1,1,1,1, 2,2,2,2 ], [ 1,1,1,2, 1,2,2,2 ] # => false
eq? [ 1,2,1,3, 4,4,5,6 ], [ 7,5,7,6, 2,2,3,4 ] # => true
```

! Edited examples so first argument is already standardized

Note: the space in the middle of the arrays is just for readability.

And I need to do this millions of times. So I came up with the following method.

```
# this method "standardizes" permutation 2 before comparing to permutation1 which is assumed to already be standardized
def eq? permutation1, permutation2
  next_val = 0
  key = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = next_val+=1 }
  permutation1 == permutation2.map { |i| key[i] }
end
```

permutation1 will be one of a few values so can be standardised once before testing, whereas each permutation2 will be unique.

But this is too slow! Is there a better way of approaching this problem, maybe with the same method but avoiding the use of a hash as a key? Or a completely different approach?

EDIT: To clarify a bit more, two arrays should be taken as equal if you can substitute each number or a subset of the numbers in ONE array, such that each original number maps onto a unique new number (i.e. 1 => 3, 3 => 4, 4 => 2, 2 => 1 etc), and then the two arrays will actually be identical. So it's not the values (they could be seven different colours or words as easily as numbers) but rather than pattern of values that matters.

EDIT2: the principle applied to a 3 digit array would mean that:

[1,1,1] matches any array where all items are the same,

[1,2,3] matches any array where all items are different,

[1,1,2] matches any array where the first two items are the same and the third is different,

[1,2,1] matches any array where the first is the same and the third but not the second,

[1,2,2] matches any array where the second and third are the same but the first is different,

any three item array will match one of these 5.

Comment: What is the pattern that make them equal?

Comment: @sawa: it looks to me like the arrays are *actually* a bag containing two bags containing 4 integers, and equality is simply normal bag equality.

Comment: @JörgWMittag That does not apply to the fourth example.

Comment: @sawa: Ah, you're right. I have misunderstood the pattern. I guess until the OP specifies what the pattern is, it's impossible to test for it.

Comment: still not clear,please give a proper example of your matching criterions.

Comment: so just explain why `[ 1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,1 ], [ 1,2,3,4, 7,6,5,1 ]` true? and how would you give input array and reference array?

Comment: @Priti because in both arrays have the pattern whereby the first and eighth items are identical but items 2 through 7 are all unique

Comment: Is there a maximum number of unique elements?

Comment: @steenslag yes, in that there cannot be more unique elements than will fit within the length of the array. Although all elements being unique is in a sense the simplest configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reformulate the match algorithm this way:

Two permutations are considered equal if they have the same number of elements and the represented object of each of their elements is equal. The represented object (or value) is one out of a set of unique objects that are assigned to the original permutation elements in the order of their appearance. The set of unique objects is the same for both permutations.

Example: you start with 2 sets of 8 integers (1..8) and compare two permutations of 8 colors.

```
for each color in both permuations
  find the color in their associated set, use the index in the set as representation
  if not found insert in the next free place and use this place's index as representation
  if representation1 != representation2 return false
continue with next element
return true
```

The main problem is to insert a permutation element and find it later quickly. This is why you have to create the hash map. One possible optimization, if you have a fixed (and small) number of elements, is to use two fixed arrays of the length of the permuatations which can hold a permuation  element in each entry. Use the index in those arrays as represented objects. You'd need a linear search for looking up a permutation in the array, but with only a small set (like the mentioned 8) this is like comparing 8 pointers/ints in a loop, which should be extremely quick, certainly not slower than a hashmap look up. But you save the creation of intermediate objects.

I have not done any verification of this myself, however.

Comment: well put! So something like: `def eq? permutation1, permutation2;
 a1 = [];
 a2 = [];
 
 permutation1.each_index do |i|;
  ind1 = a1.index(permutation1[i]);
  ind2 = a2.index(permutation2[i]);
  if ind1 == ind2;
   if ind1 == nil;
    a1 << permutation1[i];
    a2 << permutation2[i];
   end;
  else;
   return false;
  end;
 end;
 true;
end;` This is the kind of answer I was anticipating, I already accepted the other answer as satisfactory, but this is much faster!

Comment: AFAIK you can change which answer you accept, even after you did already.

Answer (score 4):

```
def eq? a, b
  (0...a.length).group_by{|i| a[i]}.values ==
  (0...b.length).group_by{|i| b[i]}.values
end

eq?([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1], [1,2,3,4,7,6,5,1]) # => true
eq?([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], [3,3,2,2,1,1,4,4]) # => true
eq?([1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], [1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2]) # => false
eq?([1,2,1,3,4,4,5,6], [7,5,7,6,2,2,3,4]) # => true
```

Comment: OP's algorithm saying something different I think,but your code output matches with him.

Comment: I didn't understand the OP's algorithm, so I didn't look at it. I followed what the OP wrote in the comments about when they should be equal.

Comment: yea, that is a more elegant solution. Seems to be very slightly quicker too. Though still involves quite an overhead in intermediate objects.

Comment: @Nat It would be better that,you just give us some visual input/output combinations.we will give you algorithm. I think it would be better. Sawa provided solution which not matched with your description algorithm. But I think it will not give you the solution,it seems your pain is in another area.

Comment: It turns out that `sort` was unnecessary. I took it off. It should become faster.

Comment: +1 @sawa, `group_by` was what my mind jumped to when I read the problem.

Comment: @Priti you mean like more examples/tests? Sawa 's solution seems to work as required. As mentioned originally I'm open to completely different approaches. It's actually better than I thought originally as in my applied context I can use a pre-calculated grouping for one of the two arrays 99% of the time.

Comment: @Nat If you are Ok,then don't need, move on. You are open you mentioned. So I will try to give another solution. :)